# How can I check and fix if there are any missing data in 'timestamp' column? There is no null value

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I am working on a time series data which is free from missing values. But by running the following commands, I am confused if there are some data missing from the 'timestamp' columns.

```
df1["Datetime"].min(), df1['Datetime'].max() 
>>(Timestamp('2016-04-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2023-03-26 15:00:00'))

df1['Datetime'].max() - df1["Datetime"].min()
>>Timedelta('2550 days 15:00:00')

df1['Hour'].max(),df1["Hour"].min() 
>>(23, 0)

df1.shape
>>(60288, 13)
```

The thing is, clearly, all the hourly data are not present in there which we can tell by calculation. I am confused wheather am I wrong or not.

There is no error problem in here. I am just trying to figure out how to check which of the hourly data are missing in a 'timestamp' column

Comment: What about the calculations is unexpected? The min and max datetimes in the `"Datetime"` column is consistent with their difference, and the max hour in any day should be `23`

Comment: With 2550 days and 24 hours daily, there should be 2550*24=61200 rows. With 15 hours on the last day, the answer should be 61200-9 days, but actually, it is much less than that. So, my guess is that there are missing values within the timestamp columns which are not even specified as null values.

Comment: "So, my guess is that…"—don't guess. You're asking us to trust that `df1` contains what you say it does, but even you aren't sure. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Create a set with the expected range of dates, then subtract from it the actual range of dates:

```
expected = set(pd.date_range('2016-04-01 00:00:00', '2023-03-26 15:00:00', freq="H"))
actual = set(df1["Datetime"].tolist())
diff = expected.difference(actual)
```